# Problem with Lenovo Touchpad

Tags: debian, kde, plasma

I used Windows 11 where suddenly my touchpad stopped working for scrolling. Looking into drivers there and reinstalling them didn't work.

Anyway I planned on switching over for Linux, Debian OS, so maybe that would fix the problem. Sadly not.

The touchpad itself is working, I can move the mouse and click on everything. It's purely the scrolling part of it.

I used the documentation to re-install Synaptics Touchpad drivers from here https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad

under my touchpad settings it's notifying me that "No touchpad was found".
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:
By typing in the code under `Determining the type of Touchpad` the following was printed out:

```
❯ egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps|elan' /proc/bus/input/devices
N: Name="ELAN06FA:00 04F3:0400 Mouse"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN06FA:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:00/i2c-0/i2c-ELAN06FA:00/0018:04F3:0400.0001/input/input5
```

Edit2:
If this is any useful information I'm using a Lenovo laptop.
https://github.com/niizam/vantage
Using this GitHub repository I downloaded the Lenovo Vantage app where it told me as well the touchpad is `deactivated`
I tried to enable it from there but nothing happened sadly, the scrolling doesn't still work.

Edit 3:
After trying to troubleshoot it more, I've so far managed to disable the device using command:
`xinput set-prop "ELAN06FA:00 04F3:0400 Mouse" "Device Enabled" 0`
I haven't found a solution for it yet but at least now my mouse won't randomly jump around because while typing my thumb accidentally touches the touchpad.

Comment: what was the result of executing the code under **Determining the type of Touchpad**

Comment: By typing in the code under `Determining the type of Touchpad` the following was printed out:

   `❯ egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps|elan' /proc/bus/input/devices` 
   `N: Name="ELAN06FA:00 04F3:0400 Mouse" `
   `P: Phys=i2c-ELAN06FA:00`
   `S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:00/i2c-0/i2c-ELAN06FA:00/0018:04F3:0400.0001/input/input5`

Comment: Please don't answer in comments, rather [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736537/edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736537/edit) your question to add more info, replies to questions, clarifications etc. Deciphering command lines from this from comments is unnecessary difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the info, made a change to the post. I was wondering why none of my markdown syntax wasn't working in the comments section.

Comment: add the kernel parameter i8042.reset to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in the /etc/default/grub file and run:

update-grub2

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RuiFRibeiro, I apologies for coming back this late to the comment. 

Sadly it did not fix the problem for me. 

If it provides any information I've noticed that for some reason I can scroll when I place my fingers at a very precise position on the touchpad- right in the middle and bottom.

Seems like it does not realise that I have a touchpad and interprets it as a mouse that would have the scrollbar around that location.